# What does `collapseContentDescription` of toolbar do?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

In Android Toolbar, I found `app:collapseContentDescription` but don't know what is it and how to use it?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:collapseContentDescription="Collapsed" />
```

Any explanation? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used to set

> Text to set as the content description for the collapse button.

see this **[link for More info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#collapseContentDescription)**

> Content Description ?

*Defines text that briefly describes content of the view. This property is used primarily for accessibility. Since some views do not have textual representation this attribute can be used for providing such.*

see this **[link for Content Description](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#contentDescription)**